# hook_form_alter : Not authorized value in a view exposed filter

Tags: 8, hooks

I am using Drupal 8.
I have a view that shows some public content and some group content.
I try to add a filter on group name as select list.
I would like to have in the select list an option to get all content
and one options by current user's group.

So I made a hook form alter

```
function btw_features_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-all-events-page") {
      $form['filter-user-group']['#type'] = 'select';
      $form['filter-user-group']['#size'] = null;

      $groups = array('All' => t(''));

      $user= \Drupal::currentUser();
      $grp_membership_service = \Drupal::service('group.membership_loader');
      $grps = $grp_membership_service->loadByUser($user);
      foreach ($grps as $grp) {
        $grpLabel = $grp->getGroup()->label();
        $groups[$grpLabel] = t($grpLabel);
      }

      $form['filter-user-group']['#options']=$groups;
      $form['filter-user-group']['#default_value'] = $form['filter-user-group']['#options']['All'];
    }
}
```

I encountered the folowing error :

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

What i made wrong ?

thanks

Comment: check this out https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271259/programatically-change-autocomplete-views-exposed-filter-by-a-select-list/271282#271282

Comment: tanks for the suggestion, finaly I found the problem,  I had a bad relation in the view

Comment: you have to add "#validated" = TRUE,
to the array http://drupaldummies.blogspot.com/2012/01/solved-illegal-choice-has-been-detected.html